# Mongoid: ActiveModel Numericality Validation, allow_nil does not work

Tags: validation, mongoid, null, activemodel

I've defined a **Mongoid model** with an Integer field for which i validate numericality like this

```rb
# source.rb
class Source
 field :code, type: Integer
 validates_numericality_of :code, allow_nil: true
```

The purpose of allow_nil is to validate fields which are present & ignore nil values.

But here, allow_nil completely bypasses the numericality check

```rb
object = Source.new
object.code = "ABC"
object.valid?
=> true
object
=> #<Source _id: 50d00b2d81ee9eae46000001, _type: nil, code: 0>
```

In activerecord, this works correctly

```rb
object = Source.new
object.code = "ABC"
object.valid?
=> false
object
=> #<Source id: nil, code: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
object.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid behaves slightly different to Active Record when using #valid? on already persisted data. Active Record's #valid? will run all validations whereas Mongoid's #valid? will only run validations on fields where data has changed as an optimization. - [see mongoid validation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html)

so this could be your problem.

you could try

`validates_numericality_of :code, :allow_nil => true`

and

`validates :code, :numericality => true ,:allow_nil => true`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand correctly. In my snippet above, both examples are new objects. Not really updating attributes. Also, if you check the first line, i'm using validates_numercality_of, similar to your first suggestion.

Comment: By the looks of it you are trying to set the `Source.code = "ABC"` this will not actually make a change to the already persisted default value of `code: 0` as its `type != Integer` so Mongoid will not run validations on the field. According to my interpretation of the Mongoid validation

Comment: Yes, interestingly ActiveRecord does as my snippet demonstrates. How would I make Mongoid fail validations?

Comment: By the looks of it Mongoid will only run validations on fields where data has changed you may have to set a custom setter for the mongoid class i.e `def code = (val) code_will_change! @code = val end`